# Target everything but IE 9

Tags: html, internet-explorer, internet-explorer-9, conditional-comments

Is there a way to only prevent IE 9 from loading a stylesheet or script?

I just found a way to prevent all IE versions from doing something but not a certain version:

```
<!--[if !IE]><!-->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="not-ie.css" />
    <script src="not-ie.js"></script>
<!--<![endif]-->
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sure, just specify the version:

```
<!--[if !(IE 9)]><!-->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="not-ie-9.css" />
    <script src="not-ie-9.js"></script>
<!--<![endif]-->
```

Note that what you currently have will result in IE10 and later loading your resources like other browsers, as those newer versions do not process conditional comments.

Comment: Super cool, thanks for the answer! I tried it without the brackets but that didn’t work.

Comment: @user1706680: I'm actually unsure if the brackets are required, but if leaving them out doesn't work after all...

Comment: Yep, without them it doesn’t work. You should alter your answer and add the brackets again.